# Heap Corruption detected: after Normal block(#176)

Tags: c++

So I got this introduction to Programming assignment, I have to write a program that find the nth member of the following sequence 1, 121, 1213121, 121312141213121.. and so on. Basically, the first member is 1, and every next one is made of [the previous member] [n] [the previous member]. N < 10. So I got this problem that I do not understand, tried searching for it in the internet but didn't get anything that can help me.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int size(int n, int realsize);
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    if (n == 1) {
        cout << "1";
        return 0;
    }
    int helper = 0;
    char c = '2';
    char* look;
    char* say;
    say = new char[size(n, 1) + 1]();
    look = new char[size(n - 1, 1) + 1]();
    look[0] = '1';
    while (helper < n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size(helper + 1, 1); i++) {
            say[i] = look[i];
        }
        say[size(helper + 1, 1)] = c;
        for (int i = size(helper + 1, 1) + 1; i < size(helper + 1, 1) * 2 + 1; i++) {
            say[i] = look[i - (size(helper + 1, 1) + 1)];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < size(helper + 1, 1) * 2 + 1; i++) {
            look[i] = say[i];
        }
        helper += 1;
    }
    cout << say;
    delete[] say;
    delete[] look;
    return 0;
}

int size(int n, int realsize)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return realsize;
    else
        return size(n - 1, realsize * 2 + 1);
}
```

Comment: ***Heap Corruption detected: after Normal block*** You are most likely going out of bounds of one or more of your dynamic arrays.

Comment: If you had used `std::vector<char>` instead of dynamic allocation, you could have used `at()` to show that you are going out of bounds of the arrays.  [See here](http://ideone.com/1tVUXC).  The last loop is where things go wrong (`look[i] = say[i];`).  Since you seem to be using Visual Studio, you should have an `out_of_range` exception thrown as soon as you made the mistake, instead of the "Heap Corruption" error when the program terminates,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the capacity of your `look` variable.  It ends out being written with the entire contents of `say`, so it needs to have that same size as well.

While I don't condone the below code as good code, it has minimal adjustments from your own implementation and should give a more solid base to continue towards a working outcome.  I tested it with the first couple of numbers, but that's no guarantee it is perfect.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int size(int n, int realsize);

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    if (n == 1)
    {
        cout << "1";
        return 0;
    }
    int helper = 0;
    char c = '2';
    char * look;
    char * say;
    say = new char[size(n, 1) + 1];     // Ditch the () call, which is confusing.
    look = new char[size(n, 1) + 1];    // Make the same size as "say"
    look[0] = '1';
    while (helper < n - 1)  // You're overrunning this loop I think, so I did it to n - 1.
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size(helper + 1, 1); i++)
        {
            say[i] = look[i];
        }
        say[size(helper + 1, 1)] = c + helper;  // You were adding '2' every time, so this will add 2, 3, 4, etc incrementally.
        for (int i = size(helper + 1, 1) + 1; i < size(helper + 1, 1) * 2 + 1; i++)
        {
            say[i] = look[i - (size(helper + 1, 1) + 1)];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < size(helper + 1, 1) * 2 + 1; i++)
        {
            look[i] = say[i];
        }
        helper += 1;
    }
    say[size(n, 1)] = '\0'; // Null-terminate "say" before printing it out.
    cout << say;
    delete[] say;
    delete[] look;
    return 0;
}

int size(int n, int realsize)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return realsize;
    else
        return size(n - 1, realsize * 2 + 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot! I fixed it, it passes the test from my professor. :)

Comment: Select it as the answer then?  :)

Comment: I'm not sure how, but I think I did it :). Thanks for the help mate!